# select command denied

Tags: mysql, sql

While trying to perform the query I get this error message. SO far everything that I have tried to do has failed me.

```
Error
SQL query: Documentation


SELECT Catagory.Category
FROM Catagory
LEFT JOIN products.Price
ON Catagory.Category=products.Price
WHERE ((Catagory.Category='Ring' OR Catagory.Category='Earings') AND (products.Price<=30))
ORDER BY products.Price LIMIT 0, 25
MySQL said: Documentation

**#1142 - SELECT command denied to user '2450097_onlinestore'@'185.176.40.25' for table 'Price'**
```

This is the code.

```
SELECT Catagory.Category
FROM Catagory
LEFT JOIN products.Price
ON Catagory.Category=products.Price
WHERE ((Catagory.Category='Ring' OR Catagory.Category='Earings') AND (products.Price<=30))
ORDER BY products.Price
```

Comment: Check privilege.

Comment: What dband db version is this?

Comment: You need to speak with the DBA (or whoever manages the database) and ask for permission to perform select statements on that table. Syntactically your query looks fine.

Comment: @TommyO I am the DBA. This DB was created for a school project.

Answer (score 0):

Check privilege first.

use mysql;

select * from user;

Answer (score 0):

The user does not have permission to execute select statements by default. You must `GRANT` the user permission:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html